# Mac OSX: Introducing a delay between paste and Enter key press, or between any keystrokes

Tags: macos

Is there a way to introduce a delay between `Cmd-V` and `Enter`? Or between a paste operation in general and an `Enter` button press being handled?

Otherwise, one of these days, I'm gonna IM something really damaging :-)

Answer (score 0):

just make sure you don't copy the newline character